# SQLite insert error in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I'm trying to do an insert statement with SQLite and I'm sure I must be doing something stupid, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

The error I'm getting is: "Error preparing statement"

Here's my code:

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

// Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// parse the JSON response into an object
NSDictionary *download = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSDictionary *buildings = [download objectForKey:@"buildings"];

// Open DB
sqlite3 *db = [RLSampleAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];

// Buildings
for (NSDictionary *building in buildings)
{
  NSDictionary *thisbuilding = [building objectForKey:@"building"];
  NSLog(@"%@", [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingname"]);
  sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
  NSString* someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO building (buildingid, buildingname) VALUES (\'%@\', \'%@\')", [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingid"], [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingname"]];

  NSLog(@"somestring: %@", someString);
  const char *sql = (const char *) someString;
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)!=SQLITE_OK)
   NSAssert1(0,@"Error preparing statement",sqlite3_errmsg(db));

  while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){}

  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
 }

[json_string release];
```

Comment: Is that code form the iCodeBlog tutorials? Because it looks like and I have been having my fair of trouble with it. I was looking for weeks, but noone was able to help me. I ended up not using this code, because Apple added Coredata functionality as of 3.x and it is way more convenient. Since SQLITE is wrapped in there, I recommend you go the same way...

Comment: I finally gave up on SQLite and have gone the Core Data route. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `NSString` instance in the `SQLite3` API. You need a pure C string.

So, try changing this:

```
const char *sql = (const char *) someString;
```

Into:

```
const char *sql = [someString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Still getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error preparing statement'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [someString UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)`

Comment: Still getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error preparing statement'

Comment: Is your statement legal if you try it on SQLite directly (like in SQLite Manager)?

Answer (score 1):

First you need sure that you get database file from Document or Library folder of simulator. Because you can not insert databases stored in the app resources. And try my code.

```
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

// Create new SBJSON parser object
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// parse the JSON response into an object
NSDictionary *download = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSDictionary *buildings = [download objectForKey:@"buildings"];

// Open DB
sqlite3 *db = [RLSampleAppDelegate getNewDBConnection];

// Buildings
for (NSDictionary *building in buildings)
{
  NSDictionary *thisbuilding = [building objectForKey:@"building"];
  NSLog(@"%@", [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingname"]);

  NSString* someString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO building (buildingid, buildingname) VALUES ('%@','%@')", [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingid"], [thisbuilding objectForKey:@"buildingname"]];


  const char *sql = [someString UTF8String];
    char *error;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"insert success.");

    }



 }

[json_string release];
```